# How to get the SUM of the subquery columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem in my query, I have the column `Last` and the value must be the SUM of column `First`,`Second`,`Third`,`Last`. But if there's a `0.00` value in one column the output of column `Last` is `0.00` but the other columns have value.

```
SELECT a.seed, a.bill_address,
  COALESCE(
    CAST((SELECT SUM(balance) 
     FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction2] 
     WHERE transaction_id IN 
       (SELECT transaction_id 
        FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction1] 
        WHERE start_date = '07-18-2023' AND customer_id = a.seed)
    ) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), 0.00
  ) AS 'Current',
  COALESCE(
    CAST((SELECT SUM(balance) 
     FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction2] 
     WHERE transaction_id IN 
       (SELECT transaction_id 
        FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction1] 
        WHERE start_date BETWEEN '07-19-2023' AND '08-18-2023' AND customer_id = a.seed)
    ) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), 0.00
  ) AS 'First',
  COALESCE(
    CAST((SELECT SUM(balance) 
     FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction2] 
     WHERE transaction_id IN 
       (SELECT transaction_id 
        FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction1] 
        WHERE start_date BETWEEN '08-19-2023' AND '09-18-2023' AND customer_id = a.seed)
    ) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), 0.00
  ) AS 'Second',
  COALESCE(
    CAST((SELECT SUM(balance) 
     FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction2] 
     WHERE transaction_id IN 
       (SELECT transaction_id 
        FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction1] 
        WHERE start_date BETWEEN '09-19-2023' AND '10-18-2023' AND customer_id = a.seed)
    ) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), 0.00
  ) AS 'Third',
  COALESCE(
    CAST((SELECT SUM(balance) 
     FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction2] 
     WHERE transaction_id IN 
       (SELECT transaction_id 
        FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction1] 
        WHERE start_date BETWEEN '10-19-2023' AND '11-18-2023' AND customer_id = a.seed)
    ) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), 0.00
  ) AS 'Last',
  --start total
  COALESCE(
    CAST(
      (
        (SELECT SUM(balance) 
         FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction2] 
         WHERE transaction_id IN 
           (SELECT transaction_id 
            FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction1] 
            WHERE start_date = '07-18-2023' AND customer_id = a.seed)
        ) 
        + 
        (SELECT SUM(balance) 
         FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction2] 
         WHERE transaction_id IN 
           (SELECT transaction_id 
            FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction1] 
            WHERE start_date BETWEEN '07-19-2023' AND '08-18-2023' AND customer_id = a.seed)
        )
        + 
        (SELECT SUM(balance) 
         FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction2] 
         WHERE transaction_id IN 
           (SELECT transaction_id 
            FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction1] 
            WHERE start_date BETWEEN '08-19-2023' AND '09-18-2023' AND customer_id = a.seed)
        )
        + 
        (SELECT SUM(balance) 
         FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction2] 
         WHERE transaction_id IN 
           (SELECT transaction_id 
            FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction1] 
            WHERE start_date BETWEEN '09-18-2023' AND '10-18-2023' AND customer_id = a.seed)
        )
        + 
        (SELECT SUM(balance) 
         FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction2] 
         WHERE transaction_id IN 
           (SELECT transaction_id 
            FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction1] 
            WHERE start_date BETWEEN '10-19-2023' AND '11-18-2023' AND customer_id = a.seed)
        )
      ) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)
    ), 0.00
  ) AS 'Total'
  --end total
FROM [dbo].[customers] AS a
WHERE a.active = 1
```

My output:

| Current | First | Second | Third | Last | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100.00 | 13010.00 | 1450.00 | 980.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| 0.00 | 2200.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |

My Target Output:

| Current | First | Second | Third | Last | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100.00 | 13010.00 | 1450.00 | 980.00 | 0.00 | 15,540.00 |
| 0.00 | 2200.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 2200.00 |

Comment: Please show both sample data and desired results, both as formatted text not images.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and do what's explained there.

Comment: I already edit my post but why my table is not responsive? but in the edit phase I see my table is working ? thanks

Comment: You need an empty line before and after your table.

Comment: You still haven't showed us the sample data that should produce your results.

Comment: what do you mean? in the first table that's already the sample data or result of my query .

Comment: Sample data is the data the feeds into your query, the raw data *before* you query it

Comment: The problem is that you need to wrap each individual plussed SUMs inside ISNULL otherwise a single null value will make it NULL which leads to zero. Also, I'm pretty sure you can solve your issue without using a bunch of copy pasted subqueries

Comment: should I put/show data from different tables? Sorry I can't catch up with you.

Comment: You showed the current result of your query and also the expected result. That's good. But we also need to see the data in your table where you select from. The best way would be to use a fiddle website and share the url.

Comment: You have `(SELECT SUM(bla)... ) + (SELECT SUM(buu)...)`, if one of those is NULL the whole thing becomes null. You need `ISNULL((SELECT SUM(bla)... ), 0)+ ISNULL((SELECT SUM(buu)...), 0)`

Comment: Yes, you should always provide a [mre] - we can't assist with a query unless we see the data before the query and the desired results after the query.

Comment: It seems totally wrong to me to use subqueries here, I guess the intended result can and should be created using `conditional aggregation`. But hard to say without sample data.

Comment: Thanks guys the question has been answered, next time @DaleK I provide the details to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try below piece of code? I have wrapped everything except the computation of `[total]` inside CTE and used it later to calculate the `[total]`.

```
;
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT a.seed, a.bill_address,
  COALESCE(
    CAST((SELECT SUM(balance) 
     FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction2] 
     WHERE transaction_id IN 
       (SELECT transaction_id 
        FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction1] 
        WHERE start_date = '07-18-2023' AND customer_id = a.seed)
    ) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), 0.00
  ) AS 'Current',
  COALESCE(
    CAST((SELECT SUM(balance) 
     FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction2] 
     WHERE transaction_id IN 
       (SELECT transaction_id 
        FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction1] 
        WHERE start_date BETWEEN '07-19-2023' AND '08-18-2023' AND customer_id = a.seed)
    ) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), 0.00
  ) AS 'First',
  COALESCE(
    CAST((SELECT SUM(balance) 
     FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction2] 
     WHERE transaction_id IN 
       (SELECT transaction_id 
        FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction1] 
        WHERE start_date BETWEEN '08-19-2023' AND '09-18-2023' AND customer_id = a.seed)
    ) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), 0.00
  ) AS 'Second',
  COALESCE(
    CAST((SELECT SUM(balance) 
     FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction2] 
     WHERE transaction_id IN 
       (SELECT transaction_id 
        FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction1] 
        WHERE start_date BETWEEN '09-19-2023' AND '10-18-2023' AND customer_id = a.seed)
    ) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), 0.00
  ) AS 'Third',
  COALESCE(
    CAST((SELECT SUM(balance) 
     FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction2] 
     WHERE transaction_id IN 
       (SELECT transaction_id 
        FROM [dbo].[bill_transaction1] 
        WHERE start_date BETWEEN '10-19-2023' AND '11-18-2023' AND customer_id = a.seed)
    ) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), 0.00
  ) AS 'Last'
FROM [dbo].[customers] AS a
WHERE a.active = 1
)
SELECT [CURRENT]
    ,[FIRST]
    ,[SECOND]
    ,[THIRD]
    ,[LAST]
    ,[CURRENT]+[FIRST]+[SECOND]+[THIRD]+[LAST] AS [TOTAL] 
FROM CTE
```

Comment: It actually works. Thanks @Madhukar.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer to my question. Thanks to @Madhukar and also I have my other query and the output is same also with @Madhukar

```
SELECT
    a.seed AS customer_id,
    a.bill_address,
    SUM(CASE WHEN bt1.start_date = '07-18-2023' THEN b.balance ELSE 0 END) AS TotalCurrent,
    SUM(CASE WHEN bt1.start_date BETWEEN '07-19-2023' AND '08-18-2023' THEN b.balance ELSE 0 END) AS TotalFirst,
    SUM(CASE WHEN bt1.start_date BETWEEN '08-19-2023' AND '09-18-2023' THEN b.balance ELSE 0 END) AS TotalSecond,
    SUM(CASE WHEN bt1.start_date BETWEEN '09-19-2023' AND '10-18-2023' THEN b.balance ELSE 0 END) AS TotalThird,
    SUM(CASE WHEN bt1.start_date BETWEEN '10-19-2023' AND '11-18-2023' THEN b.balance ELSE 0 END) AS TotalLast,
    SUM(CASE WHEN bt1.start_date = '07-18-2023' THEN b.balance
             WHEN bt1.start_date BETWEEN '07-19-2023' AND '11-18-2023' THEN b.balance ELSE 0 END) AS GrandTotal
FROM [dbo].[customers] AS a
JOIN [dbo].[bill_transaction1] AS bt1 ON a.seed = bt1.customer_id
JOIN [dbo].[bill_transaction2] AS b ON bt1.transaction_id = b.transaction_id
WHERE a.active = 1
GROUP BY a.seed, a.bill_address;
```

Comment: Much better than the other answer: it uses simple conditional aggregation instead of all those subqueries. Side notes: use an unambiguous date format such as `'20231118'`. Don't use `BETWEEN` on `datetime` values, instead use `>= ... AND ... < ...`. Seems like you should have an overall filter `WHERE bt1.start_date >= '20230718' AND bt1.start_date < '20231119'` then the final GrandTotal can be just `SUM(b.balance)`. Use better table aliases, such as `c` for `customers` and `bt2` for `bill_transaction2`.